# Parsing API jSon Array with PHP

Tags: php, json

I am stuck with the following code and not sure why I got an error code stating I have invalid argument in the foreach() statement.

```
<?php  
$url = "https://api.example.com";

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
    'accesskey: xxxxx', 
    'outputtype: json' 
);

$agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

$handle = curl_init();

curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

$response = curl_exec($handle);
$code = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ($code >= 200 || $code < 300) {
    $json_a = json_decode($response,true);
} else {
    $error = $code;
}

foreach ($json_a as $array) {
    if ($array[name] == 'Jon Doe' && $array[id] == '3') {
        $hours = $array[hours];
    }   
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<div><?php echo $hours; ?></div>
```

The api data looks like this: (updated)

```
[
 {"id":"1","name":"Chris Smith","hours":"80"},
 {"id":"2","name":"Tom Smith","hours":"70"},
 {"id":"3","name":"Jon Doe","hours":"50"}
]
```

I tried to create a similar scenario with hard coded data and it worked just fine like this:

```
$string = '[
        {
            "cID":"7239",
            "cName":"CC",
            "pID":"4",
            "occurances":"2356"
        },
        {
            "cID":"7240",
            "cName":"BB",
            "pID":"5",
            "occurances":"2126"
        },
        {
            "cID":"7250",
            "cName":"AA",
            "pID":"6",
            "occurances":"2456"
        }
]';

$json_a=json_decode($string,true);

foreach ($json_a as $array) {
    if ($array[cName] == 'CC' && $array[pID] == '4') {
        $occurance = $array[occurances];
    }   
}
```

HTML:

```
<div><?php echo $occurance; ?></div> //the result shows "2356", which is correct.
```

So I am a little confused what I am doing wrong here with the api code.

Update:

I performed a print_r(json_a) after fixing the typo (missing comma), and the API example had "1" as the result vs. the hard coded example produced the following result:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [cID] => 7239 [cName] => CC [pID] => 4 [occurances] => 2356 ) [1] => Array ( [cID] => 7240 [cName] => BB [pID] => 5 [occurances] => 2126 ) [2] => Array ( [cID] => 7250 [cName] => CC [pID] => 6 [occurances] => 2456 ) )
```

So I tried print_r(json_a[0][name]) on the API example, and nothing returned. I have been trying to understand what have I not understood, maybe cURL settings? No luck yet. Appreciate expert help, too new here.

Comment: did you really copy the api data, because there is a missing comma, after name and before "hours". Well in any case, there is a problem with $json_a(most of the time null is passed). Did you try print_r, to see if the code is properly decoding the json

Comment: Sorry it was my typo, I missed the comma, the real data has the comma in it. but it still didn't help to solve the issue.

Comment: thought so.... did you try print_r($json_a). See what result does it give...

Comment: Thank you for your continuous help. I did the print_r() test and please see the update above. Still stuck not understanding why.

Answer (score 1):

```
[
 {"id":"1","name":"Chris Smith","hours":"80"},
 {"id":"2","name":"Tom Smith","hours":"70"},
 {"id":"3","name":"Jon Doe","hours":"50"}
]
```

your api jso is wrong formatted.it should have ',' before hours key

Comment: Just updated the api data, I copied but changed to fake data for privacy.

Answer (score 0):

I did it! Here is what I figured out, it turns out I should set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to true and the code worked.

Thanks for everyone's help anyway.